# How do I hold an OpacityMask still whilst animating content underneath it in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating a countdown timer in XAML.

The numbers shift down as the timer counts down, with  the previous number and the next number faded out with a `LinearGradientBrush` applied to an `OpacityMask` as in the example below.

[image: Example of countdown timer]

I have used the following XAML to do this ...

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.OpacityMask>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0.0" EndPoint="0.5,1.0" SpreadMethod="Pad" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox">
            <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Transparent" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Transparent" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.OpacityMask>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform Y="0" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- TextBlock definitions here --->

    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

However the `LinearGradientBrush` also moves when I shift the `TranslateTransform` of the `TextBlock` container grid. It appears as though the opacity is calculated, *then* the transform is applied.

It also seems a little odd that the `LinearGradientBrush` seems to be independent of the size of the parent `Grid` that it is applied to. It appears instead that it is applied relative to its visible contents i.e. the child `Grid`. Is there a way to override this?

How can I achieve this effect of animating under a linear gradient?

**Edit:** Full code that should just be paste-able into a UserControl. To test, just adjust the transform `Y` value ...

```
<UserControl x:Class="MicroBugless.View.UserControls.CountdownWidget"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="Black">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0.0" EndPoint="0.5,1.0" SpreadMethod="Pad" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Transparent" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Transparent" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.OpacityMask>

            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="0" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="000" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="001" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="002" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="003" Foreground="White" />
            </Grid>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a `Rectangle` that overlays the `Grid` and apply the `OpacityMask` to the rectangle?

Comment: Hmm, just tried that but the `Rectangle` `OpacityMask` does not affect elements underneath it - It seems that the `OpacityMask` only affects the children of an element ...

Comment: is it possible for you to post a full working sample? provided code is not sufficient to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I think I know why is that, when you apply translate transform to the child which eventually force parent to re-layout hence the opacity mask also does get the offset. I guess a Canvas would probably solve the issue. Perhaps an `ItemsControl` with an `ScrollViewer` is a better choice here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

The `OpacityMask` is applied relative to the visible content for some reason. Translating the visible content therefore has no effect on the `OpacityMask`.

You can make the background of the parent grid very slightly opaque to ensure that the 'visible' content is defined as the boundaries of the parent Grid as desired.

i.e.

```
<Grid Background="#01000000">
    <Grid.OpacityMask>
         ...
    </Grid.OpacityMask>
    ...
    <!-- Child Grid with TranslateTransform here -->
    ...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `ItemsControl` with an `ScrollViewer`

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.OpacityMask>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0.0"
                                 EndPoint="0.5,1.0"
                                 SpreadMethod="Pad"
                                 MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox">
                <GradientStop Offset="0.0"
                              Color="Transparent" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.5"
                              Color="White" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0"
                              Color="Transparent" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.OpacityMask>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True"
                      Height="50">
            <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                           Text="000"
                           Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                           Text="001"
                           Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                           Text="002"
                           Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"
                           Text="003"
                           Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4"
                           Text="004"
                           Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5"
                           Text="005"
                           Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="6"
                           Text="006"
                           Foreground="White" />

            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

so instead of doing a translate transform you can scroll the offset of the scrollbar

Comment: That's an interesting solution. However animating a `ScrollViewer` is problematic (although not impossible) in WPF (http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9857745) so I think I prefer the simpler way of animating a `TranslateTransform` ...